# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 in Axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am beginner in react trying to make a quiz app. I am using https://peaceful-temple-16111.herokuapp.com/https://salty-cove-08526.herokuapp.com/api/countries?format=json (to avoid CORS) to get images of flags. It sends 3 images of flags at once.I display the image in div img-wrapper and I want to keep changing the flag image on submit. When the react app loads for the first time the first image is displayed but after submit the image doesnt change and get this uncaught error but the index does get updated after submit.Please Help
If you guys need any other file let me know

reactjs

```
class form extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            answer:'',
            countries:[],
            index:0,
            links : []
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        await axios.get('https://peaceful-temple-16111.herokuapp.com/https://salty-cove-08526.herokuapp.com/api/countries?format=json')
            .then(res => {
                console.log("fetched data")
                this.setState({ countries: res.data });
                let links = []
                this.state.countries.map(country =>
                    links.push(country.photo)
                )
                this.setState({
                    links
                })
            })
    }


    

    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.state.index += 1
        console.log('index=',this.state.index)
        
        const answered={
            answer:this.state.answer    
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000',answered)
        .then(response=>console.log(response.data))
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({answer:''})
        })
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            answer:e.target.value,
        })  
    }
    render(){
        let {countries} = this.state

        return (
            <div>
                <section className="login">
                    <div className="loginContainer">
                        <div className="heading">
                            Guess the <b>Country</b>
                        </div>
                      
                        <div className="img-wrapper"> 
                            <img width="250px"src={this.state.links[this.state.index]}/>
                            {console.log('file : ', this.state.links[this.state.index])}
                            {console.log('links : ', this.state.links)}
                        </div>
```

console screenshot(after the submit button is clicked once)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Woz.jpg

Comment: First get the error response paste this in your code and tell the response:- `axios.post().then().catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  });`

Comment: @PrabuReddy sorry man I got stuck at work XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:3000/game
Line Number 1, Column 1: